# How to get the dimensions from an MFC DoModal dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc

In my parent class, I have a function that is button triggered and performs a `DoModal` to display a dialog box:

```
void ParentClass::OnBtnPRess() 
{
    ChildClass dialg;
    dialg.DoModal();
}
```

In my `ChildClass`, I am programmatically creating a custom width and height of the dialog box and setting it in `SetWindowPos`, but I don't want to calculate a custom `x` and `y` position.

Instead I'd like to obtain the `rect` dimensions from the child dialog that is created upon calling `DoModal` and passing it to to `SetWindowPos`:

```
BOOL SetWindowPos(
  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  int  X,
  int  Y,
  int  cx,
  int  cy,
  UINT uFlags
);
```

What I've attempted to do was call `GetWindowRect` from `BOOL ChildClass::OnInitDialog()` to see if I can obtain the correct `rect` positions, but comparing it to the values from using **Spy++**, they're off.

How can I obtain the dimensions from the `DoModal` call and use it in my `ChildClass`?

Thanks!

For example, if I just solely rely on `DoModal` alone to set the dimension of the dialog, and not invoke `SetWindowPos` at all, I get the following from **Spy++**:

[image]

**However**, if I attempt to get the dimensions from `DoModal` by using `GetWindowRect`, and then using the values returned to `SetWindowPos`, I get the following:

[image]

The `x` positions are off. What I want are the `x` positions from invoking `DoModal`. As suggested, I've called `ScreenToClient` and `ClientToScreen` after `GetWindowRect`, but the `x` positions are off on that also.

**UPDATE:** As requested, the code in `OnInitDialog` are as follows:

```
BOOL ChildClass::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    int width;
    int height;

    // Code for calculating width and height

    SetWindowPos(&wndTop, rect.left, rect.top, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code in `ChildClass::OnInitDialog()`

Comment: The documentation says that the x and y values for `SetWindowPos()` are in client coordinates, but the rectangle returned `GetWindowRect()` is in screen coordinates. Maybe this is what makes the difference. Check out `ScreenToClient()` and `ClientToScreen()`

Comment: Could you add a picture that shows what you get vs. what you want?

Comment: As mentioned, you got to show your actual code.

Comment: Sounds like you really want to override [`CWnd::OnGetMinMaxInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#ongetminmaxinfo).